# Cards in a 5x5 grid-Probability of jack the centre

Tags: probability

All the aces, 2’s, 3’s, 4’s, 5’s and 6’s, as well as the jack of diamonds are taken from a regular deck of 52 playing cards, and then placed face up on a table in a 5×5 square grid configuration randomly. If all 9 cards of the centre 3×3 grid are red, what is the probability that the card in the centre of the grid is the jack of diamonds?

How would one go about setting up this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider just the subset of red cards. There are thirteen in the subset. The jack of diamonds has a 13/13 chance (100%) of being in that set.  If you partition that set into two subsets, one with nine elements and one with four then the jack of hearts has a 9/13 chance of being in the first and a 4/13 chance of being in the second. Given that all of the nine center cards are red we know that there is a 9/13 chance that the jack of diamonds in in the nine center cards.

If the jack of diamonds is in the center nine it has a 1/9 chance of being in the exact center and a 8/9 chance of being in a different position.

For the jack of hearts to be in the center of the 5x5 grid it must satisfy both conditions: 1) that it be in the center nine red sub set (p=9/13) and 2) that it be in the center of those nine (p=1/9):

```
P = 9/13 * 1/9 = 1/13.
```

So, given that the nine center cards are red, the jack of diamonds has a 1/13 chance of being in the center of the 5x5 grid.

Answer (score 0):

I might very well be wrong about this.  But I figure there are $\dfrac{13!}{4!}$ ways the middle 9 cards are red. (There are 13 red cards so there are 13 choices for the first, 12 for the next, etc.)  If we restricted the middle to the jack of diamonds there are $\dfrac{12!}{3!}$ ways the remaining 8 cards are red. (Same reasoning).  So the probability of the Jack of Diamonds in the center is:

$\dfrac{\frac{12!}{3!}}{\frac{13!}{4!}} = \dfrac{12!}{3!}\dfrac{4!}{13!} = \dfrac 4{13}$

Answer (score 0):

The jack of diamonds is one of the $13$ red cards in the deck (there are 6 hearts and 7 diamonds).

Given that the central card is red (because all those in the $3\times 3$ centre grid are red), then the probability that the central card is $\color{red}{J\diamondsuit}$ is $1/13$.

It's not any more complicated than that.